# Are short codes required in the U.S. for SMS applications?

Tags: sms

Simple question:  I'm researching SMS gateways for the U.S.  We've implemented in Europe before, but I can't determine if renting a "short code" is required for for subscription automated outbound SMS traffic in the U.S. or if that just varies by SMS gateway provider.  My hunch is that it is required, expensive as it is, but I need confirmation before I'm comfortable presenting that to my manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies by carrier.  Some carriers will allow you to use an email gateway for a production-level application; some will not.

More to the point, you will have far, far less headaches down the road by actually using the short code and native SMS than an email gateway, which tend to have fairly diverse latency, availability, and functionality behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I previously worked for a company that did some SMS work, and I believe a short code is required.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, most SMS gateway providers in the U.S. don't require a special short code for outbound SMS. I am using SMS in an app right now without my own shortcode.

They do require it for **inbound** SMS though. There are alternatives to that too, as you can use a service like [Textmarks](http://www.textmarks.com).